# How do i get BST from a given array?

Tags: c++

I am using the following Logic

1. Create an empty stack.
2. Make the first value as root. Push it to the stack.
3. Keep on popping while the stack is not empty and the next value is greater than stack’s top value. Make this value as the right child of the last popped node. Push the new node to the stack.
4. If the next value is less than the stack’s top value, make this value as the left child of the stack’s top node. Push the new node to the stack.
5. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until there are items remaining in pre[].

And my code is:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct BST{
    int node;
    struct BST *lc;
    struct BST *rc;
};

int main(){
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--){
        int N;
        cin>>N;
        int arr[N];

        struct BST **tree=new struct BST*[N];

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
            cin>>arr[i];
            tree[i]=new struct BST();
            tree[i]->node=arr[i];
            tree[i]->lc = NULL;
            tree[i]->rc = NULL;
        }
        stack<struct BST*> s;
        struct BST *root;
        root=tree[0];
        s.push(root);
        struct BST* temp1=NULL;
        struct BST* temp2=NULL;

        for(int i=1;i<N;i++){
            //greater value && stack not empty
            cout<<"searching for "<<tree[i]->node<<"\n";
            if(tree[i]->node < (s.top()->node)){
                s.top()->lc=tree[i];
                cout<<tree[i]->node<<" is lc of "<<s.top()->node<<"\n";
                s.push(tree[i]);
                cout<<"pushed "<<tree[i]->node<<"\n";

            }else{
                while(tree[i]->node > (s.top()->node) && !(s.empty())){
                    temp2=s.top();
                    temp1=temp2;
                    cout<<"popped "<<temp1->node<<"\n";
                    s.pop();
                }
                    cout<<"temp holds "<<temp1->node<<"\n";
                    temp1->rc=tree[i];
                    cout<<tree[i]->node<<" is rc of "<<temp1->node<<"\n";
                    s.push(tree[i]);
            }

        }




    }
    return 0;
}
```

For input

```
1
6
10 5 1 7 40 50
```

I am able to get the output till element 7 but then there is some error. What is the correct way to get the BST?

Comment: If you just want to create a BST from given array, isn't it just adding elements to BST one by one?

Comment: I forgot to mention, the given array is preorder traversal of a Binary Tree.

Comment: `while(tree[i]->node > (s.top()->node) && !(s.empty())){` It's kind of pointless to check `s.empty()` **after** you've already accessed `s.top()`. If the stack is in fact empty, your program has already exhibited undefined behavior.